# bind9 not working when starting bind9 service but works when explicitly starting named

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, master-slave

I have a really odd situation I don't fully understand.  I have a master and slave DNS, I've checked the configuration, and no errors are returned.  if I try to start bind9 as a service, it fails to properly sync with the slave:

```
sudo service bind9 start
```

I've also tried enabling it with:

```
sudo systemctl enable bind9
```

Again, the master and slave don't sync.  I was digging through and someone suggested running **named** in the foreground to see what the logs output.  Oddly enough, when I run `service bind9 stop` and then run `named -fg` on the master and slave, suddenly they begin to sync and transfer necessary zone information.

Why would they be transferring when I explicitly run named, but not when I run bind9 as a service?  I thought named and bind were just aliases of eachother, so I'm not really sure I understand the difference of what is happening in one case versus another.

**Edit:**

Using Raspberry Pi: Raspbian Lite
A systemctl status bind9 output looks like the following:

```
> shutting down: flushing changes stopping command channel on
> 127.0.0.1#953 dumping master file: /etc/bind/tmp-ew7u3atsWd: open: permission denied dumping master file: /etc/bind/tmp-CAP7c5Elmn: open:
> permission denied no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53 no longer
> listening on 192.168.0.105#53 no longer listening on 10.1.10.29#53
> exiting bind9.service: Succeeded. Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
```

**Second Edit**

I didn't think it was permissions because I had set the group and user ownership to bind:bind for everything except rndc.key, but it turns out it was.

After being pointed to potential permissions issues, I did the following:

- chown bind:bind /etc/bind/named.conf
- chown root:root /etc/bind/rndc.key
- chmod 755 rndc.key
- chown bind:bind /var/cache/bind/
- chmod g+w /var/cache/bind/
- chmod g+w /etc/bind/

Since then it looks like it is now properly updating.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? Have you tried to configure debugging parameters in `named` configuration, such as a custom log file? Have you checked systemd's journal? The problem looks like a permission error caused by standard access controls or a security layer such as SELinux.

Comment: please give some more details: os type, output of systemctl status bind9, output of the system logs. Is bind9 part of the os packages, or is it a self compiled? With the provided information we cannot help you.

Comment: Does `named` run with the same command line (other than `-fg`) when started as a service? In particular, is there a `-t` argument? Other than that, SELinux or systemd unit restrictions are plausible reasons, particularly if you have customized paths in conflict with what the package maintainer has prepared.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think it was permissions because I had set the group and user ownership to bind:bind for everything except rndc.key, but it turns out it was.

After being pointed to potential permissions issues, I did the following:

- chown bind:bind /etc/bind/named.conf
- chown root:root /etc/bind/rndc.key
- chmod 755 rndc.key
- chown bind:bind /var/cache/bind/
- chmod g+w /var/cache/bind/
- chmod g+w /etc/bind/

Since then it looks like it is now properly updating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you placed your master file into `/etc/bind/` while it should be into `/var/lib/bind/`.
The bind service is not allowed to write into `/etc/bind/` while bind process need to write a binary version of your zone file (jnl file) in same folder.
So move your master zone file to `/var/lib/bind/` and update the file you put into `named.conf.local`